# WAIT: (WrLpcReceive) without a message?

Tags: multithreading, windbg

I have a kernel dump for a system hang and I stumbled upon some occupied ALPC ports in the system thread. From nt!AlpcpReceiveMessage I can see the port the thread is waiting on. From the Port I can see the thread that is waiting. But the Thread itself does not indicate the typical - `thread X is waiting for ALPC message Y on ALPC port Z`.

Thread:

```
0: kd> !thread fffffa80069dc040
THREAD fffffa80069dc040  Cid 0004.00b0  Teb: 0000000000000000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 WAIT: (WrLpcReceive) UserMode Non-Alertable
    fffffa80069dc408  Semaphore Limit 0x1
Not impersonating
DeviceMap                 fffff8a000008ca0
Owning Process            fffffa80069a9740       Image:         System
Attached Process          N/A            Image:         N/A
Wait Start TickCount      16772          Ticks: 501 (0:00:00:07.815)
Context Switch Count      408            IdealProcessor: 4             
UserTime                  00:00:00.000
KernelTime                00:00:00.000
Win32 Start Address nt!PopUmpoMessageThread (0xfffff8000308c8e4)
Stack Init fffff88003952c70 Current fffff88003952470
Base fffff88003953000 Limit fffff8800394d000 Call 0
Priority 14 BasePriority 13 UnusualBoost 0 ForegroundBoost 0 IoPriority 2 PagePriority 5
Child-SP          RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
fffff880`039524b0 fffff800`030c45f2 : 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`069dc040 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000009 : nt!KiSwapContext+0x7a
fffff880`039525f0 fffff800`030d599f : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiCommitThreadWait+0x1d2
fffff880`03952680 fffff800`033dc5f9 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000010 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeWaitForSingleObject+0x19f
fffff880`03952720 fffff800`033dc07c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!AlpcpReceiveMessagePort+0x189
fffff880`03952780 fffff800`033ddd56 : fffffa80`069db1c0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`069db1c0 : nt!AlpcpReceiveMessage+0x2d9
fffff880`03952820 fffff800`030cde53 : fffffa80`069dc040 fffff880`039529c0 fffff880`03952af8 fffff800`0320230d : nt!NtAlpcSendWaitReceivePort+0x1e6
fffff880`039528d0 fffff800`030ca410 : fffff800`0308c996 00000000`00000000 fffff880`03952b30 00000000`6f706d55 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13 (TrapFrame @ fffff880`03952940)
fffff880`03952ad8 fffff800`0308c996 : 00000000`00000000 fffff880`03952b30 00000000`6f706d55 00000000`000007ff : nt!KiServiceLinkage
fffff880`03952ae0 fffff800`0336a73a : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!PopUmpoMessageThread+0xb2
fffff880`03952c00 fffff800`030bf8e6 : fffff880`009b3180 fffffa80`069dc040 fffffa80`069c6040 00000000`00000000 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`03952c40 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`03953000 fffff880`0394d000 fffff880`03952470 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxStartSystemThread+0x16
```

Port:

```
0: kd> !alpc /p fffffa80`069db1c0
Port  fffffa80069db1c0
  Type                      : ALPC_CONNECTION_PORT
  CommunicationInfo         : fffff8a0000a3230
    ConnectionPort          : fffffa80069db1c0 (PowerPort)
    ClientCommunicationPort : 0000000000000000
    ServerCommunicationPort : 0000000000000000
  OwnerProcess              : fffffa80069a9740 (System)
  SequenceNo                : 0x00000001 (1)
  CompletionPort            : 0000000000000000
  CompletionList            : 0000000000000000
  ConnectionPending         : No
  ConnectionRefused         : No
  Disconnected              : No
  Closed                    : No
  FlushOnClose              : Yes
  ReturnExtendedInfo        : No
  Waitable                  : No
  Security                  : Static
  Wow64CompletionList       : No

  1 thread(s) are waiting on the port:

    THREAD fffffa80069dc040  Cid 0004.00b0  Teb: 0000000000000000 Win32Thread: 0000000000000000 WAIT

  Main queue is empty.


  Large message queue is empty.


  Pending queue is empty.


  Canceled queue is empty.
```

- What causes (or could cause) a thread to not indicate the message it
  is waiting on? Or - what could cause a thread to await a port that has no message?

Comment: If you leave a negative score it is common courtesy to comment as to why. If you think this question does not fit the rules of the community please let me know why. If you think it is a stupid question but fits the rules of the community then feel free to let me know I'm an idiot but don't down-vote the question

Answer (score 1):

Thats a receiver thread.  This one is listening n waiting for lpc messages. In other words its idle.

If you are looking for a alpc wait chain you should look for threads with WrLPCReply or something similar.